# Uses of typ in anova_lm()

Tags: python, statsmodels, anova

Sorry, I'm new to python and stats. And I was curious about the `typ` in the `anova_lm()` function.
What does typ 1,2,3 mean and how do they differ?
This is an example code of the `typ=2` used.

```py
aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(results, typ=2)
aov_table
```

Answer (score 5):

the documentation of [statsmodels.stats.anova.anova_lm](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.anova.anova_lm.html#statsmodels.stats.anova.anova_lm) states:

```
typ: str or int {“I”,”II”,”III”} or {1,2,3}

The type of Anova test to perform. See notes.
```

You can read about the types of ANOVA for example [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/anova-%E2%80%93-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/). The difference is how you account for unbalance data and how you perform the calculation of sums of squares. This choice is based on your data. To quote from there:

> In general, if there is no significant interaction effect, then type
>   II is more powerful, and follows the principle of marginality. If
>   interaction is present, then type II is inappropriate while type III
>   can still be used, but results need to be interpreted with caution (in
>   the presence of interactions, main effects are rarely interpretable).

There has also been many posts on stack-exchange on which one to choose and how to interpret your results.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345684/which-one-to-choose-type-i-type-ii-or-type-iii-anova

Hope that helps.